# implement a transition effect between addClass and removeClass

Tags: jquery, css

```
$('.greenBox').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('expanded');
    $(this).removeClass('contracted');
}, function(){
    $(this).removeClass('expanded');
    $(this).addClass('contracted');
}); // end of hover state for green box
```

Wondering if there is a way to implement a transition with the above jquery logic? Between the adding or removing of the class.

I have tried the below, but it did not work: *(It is a simple div small height > large height toggle)*

```
.expanded {
    height: auto;
    // to make the box move up add back the bottom 300px
    // bottom: 300px;
    background: linear-gradient(#812990, #9e248e);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear; 
    transition-timing-function: linear; 
}
```

***also:***

```
.contracted {
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: That entirely depends on what styles those classes apply. Depending on that, you could theoretically do this in CSS alone.

Comment: Toggling of heights.

Comment: What does the `.contracted` class look like?

Comment: Headsup: you can NOT transition to/from `auto` values in CSS. Also you need both states for a transition to work and you haven't set a `transition` property. [More info](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/)

Comment: You need to specify the `transition` setting in your CSS. Although, as @LuudJacobs says you cannot transition from/to `height: auto` so you would need to deal in concrete sizes. Here's a working CSS-only demo: http://jsfiddle.net/76n6Luc8/

Comment: Set "transition-property:height" in your class "expanded"

Comment: Also you cannot transtion to/from auro in Jquery *natively*..a plugin is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the `transition` to your `.greenbox` class, rather than either of the 2 you're adding & removing:

```
.greenbox{
    transition:height .5s linear;
}
```

Having said that, you cannot transition to or from an `auto` value in CSS so, the trick you would want to use here is to instead set the `max-height` of the expanded class to a value greater than the height its contents can ever be and transition that, instead.

```
.greenbox{
    transition:max-height .5s linear;
}
.contracted{
    max-height:100px;
}
.expanded{
    max-height:1000px;/* adjust to suit your content */
}
```

Depending on the value you set for the larger `max-height`, you may need to tweak the timing of the transition to improve how it looks.

Incidentally, you could achieve this entirely with CSS with absolutely no need for any JavaScript, like so:

```
.greenbox{
    max-height:100px;
    transition:max-height .5s linear;
}
.greenbox:hover{
    max-height:1000px;/* adjust to suit your content */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can simplify the JavaScript and only have one class that you toggle. You can't use CSS to animate to auto, because it's not aware of what that means, but you can trick it with max-height... You'll have to just be arbitrary and get closest to the common size. Otherwise you'll have to use jQuery animate (or velocity) and query the height so you know what integer to animate to - and then leave the CSS transition out.

### jQuery

```
$('.greenBox').hover( function() {
    $(this).addClass('expanded');
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('expanded');
});
```

### CSS

```
.greenbox {
  height: 864572px;
  max-height: 100px;
  transition: .2s; 
}

.greenbox.expanded {
  max-height: 500px
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/zu49xmhz/)

Comment: You have to have a `height: Npx;` as well. With width you can add a width 100%, but height is a little whacky - because the DOM doesn't usually know what `100%` means... 100% of what? etc.

Comment: Where do I add height height: Npx; ?

Comment: That may have been confusing. I meant `N` to be a placeholder. In my example I have defined the height of the box.